# Mplayer через PHP, Terminal type `unknown' is not defined

Tags: php, видео, exec

Пытаюсь запустить видео через Mplayer в PHP такой командой:

```
echo exec('mplayer -fs -ontop /home/parallels/www/temp/p05.mp4 < /dev/null', $output );
```

На что получаю такой output

> Load subtitles in /home/parallels/www/temp/array ( 0 => 'MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team', 1 => 'Terminal type `unknown\' is not defined.', 2 => '', 3 => 'Playing /home/parallels/www/temp/p01.mp4.', 4 => 'libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)', 5 => 'Mismatching header version 54.20.3', 6 => 'libavformat file format detected.', 7 => '[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0', 8 => '[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang eng', 9 => 'VIDEO: [H264] 1280x720 24bpp 25.000 fps 1422.4 kbps (173.6 kbyte/s)', 10 => 'Clip info:', 11 => ' major_brand: mp42', 12 => ' minor_version: 1', 13 => ' compatible_brands: mp42mp41', 14 => ' creation_time: 2015-11-13 13:58:37', 15 => 'Load subtitles in /home/parallels/www/temp/', )

Как дальше жить - непонятно. С правами проблем нет, из консоли запускается все нормально, сам видеофайл существует.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите запускать проигрыватель через PHP себе на экран, я думаю стоит тогда и PHP запускать от своего пользователя или выполнять команду от своего пользователя.
Проблема у вас наверняка в этом.

Comment: а можно как нибудь установить apache таким образом, чтобы php всегда запускался от имени пользователя?